# (Android Kotlin) How to retrieve the image "Name" from firebase storage on a Button click in a recyclerView?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview

**Goal:** 
To retrieve the default image "name" from the images present in firebase storage, on click of a button, such that the name can be stored in a local txt file. (which will be used to filter out images later on).

**Setup so Far:**

- Have created the recyclerView which is displaying images from the firebase storage in a cardView.
- Each card in the recyclerView contains only the image and a button, "doneButton".
- Have setup the function to save strings in a local txt file.

**Where I'm Stuck:**

- Not able to retrieve the image name from storage on button click,
  both of which (button & image) are present on a card in the
  recyclerView.
- Once the name is retrieved, on the same button click action, need to pass
  the image name to the save image name function to    write it to a
  local txt file.

Would be really helpful if someone can help out with this. Thank you. (FYI: I'm new to android development)

**Main Activity:**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers_tab)


    //firebase
    val storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
    val storageRef = storage.reference.child("Images")
    val imageList:ArrayList<CoronaImages> = ArrayList()


    val listAllTask: Task<ListResult> = storageRef.listAll()
    listAllTask.addOnCompleteListener{ result ->
        val items: List<StorageReference> = result.result!!.items

        //cycle for adding image URL to list
        items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
            item.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.d("item","$it")
                imageList.add(CoronaImages(it.toString()))
            }.addOnCompleteListener{

                ImageRecyclerView.adapter = ImageAdapter(imageList, this)
                ImageRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Adapter** (with an attempt to create the OnClickListener for image name):

```
class ImageAdapter (
        private var coronaImage: List<CoronaImages>, private val context: Context):
        RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.corona_images, parent, false)
        )
    }

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = coronaImage[position]
    Picasso.get()
        .load(item.imageUrl)
        .into(holder.imageView)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return coronaImage.size
}

class ViewHolder(view: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view), View.OnClickListener {
        val imageView: ImageView=view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1)


// this is where I'm stuck:
        val doneButton: CardView=view.findViewById(R.id.doneButton)

        init {
            doneButton.setOnClickListener {
                object : View.OnClickListener {
                        override fun onClick(v: View?) {


             // how can I retrieve the image name and pass it to the writeToFile ()??


                        writeToFile(????)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // Function to Write to a File
            fun writeToFile(FirebaseImageName: String) {
            try {
                var writeData = FileWriter("doneCoronaImages.txt", true)
                writeData.write(FirebaseImageName +"\n")
                writeData.close()
            }
            catch (ex: Exception) {
                print("Could not save the image name.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Data Class for Image URLs:

```
data class CoronaImages(
    var imageUrl: String
)
```

coronaImage XML

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="455dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Media -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="390dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <!-- Buttons -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/coronaButton"               style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Icon"
                android:layout_width="90sp"
                android:layout_height="55sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:text="@string/coronaButtonTitle"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
doneButton.setOnClickListener {
      val item = coronaImage[adapterPosition] // get image item
      val imageName = File(item.imageUrl).name // get image name
      writeImageNameToFile(context, "doneCoronaImages.txt", imageName)
}
```

or

```
view.setOnClickListener {
      val item = coronaImage[adapterPosition] // get image item
      val imageName = File(item.imageUrl).name // get image name
      writeImageNameToFile(context, "doneCoronaImages.txt", imageName)
}
```

Create folder and write to file.

```
fun writeImageNameToFile(
context: Context,
fileName: String?,
imageName: String?
) {
    try {
        val root = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), "YourFolder")
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs() // create folder if you want
        }
        // val root = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null)?.absolutePath) // use this line if you don't want to create folder
        val txtFile = File(root, fileName)
        val writer = FileWriter(txtFile, true)
        writer.appendln(imageName)
        writer.flush()
        writer.close()
        Toast.makeText(context, "Saved image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

> Device File Explorer -> storage -> emulated -> 0 -> Android -> Data ->
>   YourPackageName -> files -> YourFolder -> doneCoronaImages.txt

Comment: Thank you Kasim, but the issue that I'm facing with the solution you suggested is, "[adapterPosition] throws an error. Because may be we are calling it in the ViewHolder class.

I'm able to get the position with just "[Position]", but for that I need to place the buttonClickListener in the onBindViewHolder(). And issue with that is I'm able to access the "doneButton" in the onBindViewHolder().

I tried placing the buttonListener in onCreateViewHolder(), because we can access the button there, but again was not able to get the image [Position] there.

Would you be able to help here?

Comment: You just use inner class ViewHolder. And remove View.OnClickListener. You don't need to do anything else. https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxcLQ.png

Comment: Yes, wow! This problem is solved.
But this line is causing fatal crash error:
"val doneButton: CardView=view.findViewById(R.id.doneButton)"

Comment: Yes, it is present in a card view. The layout structure of the activity is this: Recycler View > which contains a material card view > which contains (image view in a linear layout + a button view in a second linear layout, below the image button). Have just added the CardView XML above for reference.

Comment: CardView id is "card" not "doneButton". Actually you can use "view.setOnClickListener". No need cardView.

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to save the image name on tapping a button (not the card), the button is present on the card. Here's the app screen: shorturl.at/aqyDJ
And here's the screenshot of the Image Adapter code: shorturl.at/CET58
(able to run the app but still the image name is not saving in the txt file. Tried with tapping the card as well with "view.setOnClickListener").

Comment: Why do you use "View.Onclicklistener". just use view.setOnClickListener as like my answer.

Comment: If you want to click blue view. You have to define it like imageView. Then you can add click listener.

Comment: It worked, have added the listener on the button. Actually it was already working on the card view listener, but I didn't realize it because I was looking for the txt file at a wrong place. But now I can see it. The change that I made is to use [absoluteAdapterPosition] at this place: "val item = coronaImage[adapterPosition]". Because [adapterPosition] is deprecated.